# Comparing two dates (current date and date from database)

Tags: sql, objective-c, nsdate

i am trying to compare two dates one from the database and the other one is the current date of the system .the date  from the database is parsed into a string and i want to transform it into  `NSDate`  . the problem that im facing is that `NewsDate` is `nil`.

```
  -(void)viewDidLoad
    {

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     self.title=self.ntitle;
     _lblDate.text=self.ndateNews;
     _lblDetail.text=self.ndetails;
     _lblTitre.text=self.title;
     NSDate *currDate=[NSDate date];
     NSDateFormatter *DateFormats=[[NSDateFormatter alloc ]init];
     [DateFormats setDateFormat:@"MM-DD-yyyy hh:mm:ss +EEEE"];
     NSLog(@"selected date  %@",self.ndateNews);
     NSDate *NewsDate=[DateFormats dateFromString:self.ndateNews];
     NSLog(@"string transformed   into date %@",NewsDate);
     NSLog(@" system date %@",currDate);



     if ([currDate isEqualToDate:NewsDate]){

        _lblDate.text=@"today";

    }

}
```

Comment: `NewsDate` is `nil` as `self.ndateNews` cannot be parsed correctly - its probably not in the same format as `MM-DD-yyyy hh:mm:ss +EEEE`. What does `NSLog(@"%@", self.ndateNews);` output?

Comment: Also a note that `EEEE` is for *week days* according to the [format docs](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: 2014-04-16T00:00:00+03:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong date format pattern [see this page for info](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ
```

Is what you want for your date format.

Also if you want to check that `NewsDate` is today you should use:

```
BOOL today = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] isDateInToday:NewsDate];
```

Checking if a date is equal to `NSDate date` would me that the dates would have to matches *exactly* - down to the millisecond!

Note that [`-isDateInToday:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000742-CH2-SW49) is **iOS 7 only**. Leave me a comment if you want a version that works for iOS 6 too :)

Comment: No problem - I hope the today check also help with that issue too :)

Comment: ` - (BOOL)isDateInToday:(NSDate *)date NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 8_0); ` So it's only available for iOS 8.